# loading an array from text file in javascript

Tags: jquery, arrays, text-files, jquery-autocomplete

I try to do some autocomplete on my site.
I found solution using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
```

And it works fine, but I need to load data form text file. I need a way to make `var availableTags` from text like:

```
ruby
java
javascript
```

and so on.

Comment: Use an AJAX server script to read the file and generate the completion entries. The jquery autocomplete documentation shows how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a simple get request and split the result on new lines. I'd use `$.get()`.

```
$.get('languages.txt', function(txtFile){
  var languages = txtFile.split("\n");
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: languages
  });
});
```

Comment: so simple :) looks even better now :) a long long way before me :)